# Reverse Proxy HTTPS Requests as HTTP to Upstream Server

Tags: nginx

We are using NGINX on our cPanel server to reverse proxy ZKTeco ZKBioSecurity servers. Due to compatibility with some of their devices not supporting HTTPS, all our servers use HTTP, but, of course, all sessions to our NGINX server is secured with HTTPS and a Sectigo certificate provided by cPanel’s AutoSSL.

**Here’s the problem:** it seems that the ZKBioSecurity servers are detecting that the client is using HTTPS to connect to them through NGINX, and because of this, give the following prompt each time you want to log in, advising you to download and install the ISSOnline driver and certificate. The certificate, however, is issued to the ZKBioSecurity server for 127.0.0.1, so of course this is rather pointless as we are connecting to the NGINX server using a FQDN. This does not happen if we use HTTP:

[image: Driver Detection Exception Prompt]

**So my question:** is there something in the request (the HTTP header perhaps?) that NGINX forwards to the upstream server that contains the protocol (HTTPS) the client used to connect to the server? Because this somehow seems to be the case.

Here’s our NGINX config for ZKBioSecurity servers:

```sh
location /.well-known {

    root /home/novacloud/public_html/subdomain/.well-known;
    allow all;
    try_files $uri = 404;

}

location / {

    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1:8080;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection        "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;

}
```

The `server_name` directive is, of course, managed by cPanel. The above is an example of the include files we use in the main cPanel NGINX configuration file. I thought it was the `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme`, but even if I remove this, I still get the `Driver Detection Exception` prompt.

[Here’s a Pastebin of a cURL of the ZKBioSecurity server from our cPanel/NGINX server](https://pastebin.com/bP6CRcfs)

Comment: Do "ZKBioSecurity" support to talk via http? Have you asked there Support because it looks like this is a Product which you need to buy.

Comment: Hi @Aleksandar. Thanks for the comment. Yes, definitely. The reason we’re using NGINX is due to ZKBioSecurity lacking the ability to run multiple sites from a single installation. This means that we have to create a new Windows VM for each site we deploy. So to save on public IPs we use NGINX.

Comment: To which question is "Yes, definitely." the answer?

Comment: Yes, that ZKBioSecurity supports HTTP connections. It’s basically Apache Tomcat.

Comment: what do you get when you exec this `curl -v http://192.168.0.1:8080` on nginx server

Comment: Thanks again for the reply @Aleksandar. I have updated my question.

Comment: Okay nothing shows why the Product shows you this `Driver Detection Exception`. What does this message means? Have you open a ticket to the vendor about this Exception?